# The code first development using the EF many-to-many how to bind data to repeater?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, many-to-many

BlogPost and Category-many relationship, if the dataset directly bind repeater, now how to use code first developed to bind repeater?

```
public class BlogPost
    {
        public int BolgID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int ID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual ICollection<Category> Category
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

public class Category
    {
        public int ID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual ICollection<BlogPost> BlogPost
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}



   using(MyDemoContext context = new MyDemoContext())
                {
                    DbSet<BlogPost> post = context.Set<BlogPost>();
                        var v = post.Include(p=>p.Category).Where(p=>p.ID==5).ToList();
                        Repeater1.DataSource = v;
                        Repeater1.DataBind();
                }
```

BlogID
                        BlogTitle
                        CategoryTitle//Category's title

```
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("ID")%></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Title")%></td>
                <td><%# Eval("")%></td>//here how to bind Category.Ttitle?
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
        </FooterTemplate>

        </asp:Repeater>
```

How to get this result：

```
BlogID  BlogTitle  CategoryTitle

   5       test         C#

   5       test         asp.net

   5       test         VB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catgory and BlogPost has many to many relation, so on blog post will have multiple categories. I am not sure which category title you want to show here - typically, I would probably show a comma separated list (or perhaps a bulleted list), this can be achieve by nesting a repeater. For example,

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <tr>
     <td><%# Eval("ID")%></td>
     <td><%# Eval("Title")%></td>
     <td>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="C" DataSource='<%# Eval("Category") %>'>
           <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Title") #></ItemTemplate>
           <SeparatorTemplate>, </SeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
     </td>
   </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

*Diclaimer: untested code*

Noe above template will generate comma seperated list but you can adjust layout as per your need.

Comment: thx but I want the results mentioned above, what better way to do

Comment: @yao, if you have a single category per blog post then above code will give you the same result!

Comment: that's one-to-many, and now I don't know how to handle many to many:(